# How to add ViewModel in service using Koin?

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I'm new using Koin and I want to know how to use a ViewModel inside a Service. I'm using this ViewModel in an activity and in a fragment and I need to all of this (service, activity and fragment) have the same instance, it is possible?

Comment: Using VM in a Service is against the entire idea of MVVM.

Comment: How can I use Retrofit in a service? Wich is the best way?

Comment: Post your code, what you are trying to do

Comment: For a reason I can't post code but I'm trying to make an API call every 25 seconds in background and use this response in an activity and fragment.

Comment: I suggest you to look into to WorkManager. 

if that is not possible,


call retrofit inside  your service, then get the response into view model via interface or something, 
and there by update fragment/activity

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful sometimes. To do this, just inject your view model by inject() instead of viewModel() and extend KoinComponent on your Service class